# Weird behaviour with `timeit` python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, benchmarking, timeit

I am using python 3.8.10

a wrote a function to calculate fibonacci which uses the `lru_cache` from functools

```py
@lru_cache
def fast_fib(n):
    if n in [0, 1]: return n
    else:
        return fast_fib(n-1) + fast_fib(n-2)
```

I am trying to benchmark the execution time with the timeit function from `timeit` module.

```py
from timeit import timeit

tmp = [0]*10000001
for z in range(1000001):
    print(f"Calculating fib({z})")
    tmp[z] = timeit("fast_fib(z)", globals=locals(), number=100)/100
    print(tmp[z])
```

But i run into some weird behaviour:

1. I am meant to encounter a `recursion_limit` error at arount `n=1000`, But I don't
2. The execution time remains really small (like `2e-7 seconds`) even for really large `n`
   I checked the function without the timeit, and I get the `recursion_limit` error like I'm supposed to, and the time takes as long as I expected for large `n`

What's the cause of this "weird" behaviour in the timeit function, I there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to benchmark the function?

Comment: "I am meant to encounter a recursion_limit error at arount n=1000, But I don't" The code never recurses that deeply, because the loop keeps trying increasing values of `z`, which *builds up the cache* for the next calls. "The execution time remains really small (like 2e-7 seconds) even for really large n" Again, because of the caching. Even without the `for z` loop, `fast_fib(z)` would run instantly every time except the first, because the value is in the cache. If you are asking this question, it is not clear exactly what you expect `@lru_cache` to do.

Comment: Did you perhaps want to empty the cache between trials?

Comment: If curious, I did earlier do some comparisons for versions of fib using the timeit module [here](https://github.com/rnag/code-solutions/tree/main/dsa/basic/fibonacci). I haven't tested with the `lru_cache` approach though, even though that would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Because you are adding caching... this isn't weird at all, this is the *whole point of caching*. how did you expect that caching to behave?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is caused by the ordering of the sequence of arguments passed to `fast_fib`. If a descending `range(1000001, 1, -1)` were used instead of an ascending `range(1000001)`, your code would both hit the recursion limit and run for a long time for high `n`.

Why? Since `fast_fib` is using the `@lru_cache` decorator, results of past `fast_fib` calls are retained and reused. Normally, `fast_fib` would recursively call itself on `n-2` and `n-1`, but since in your test it is called on an ascending sequence of consecutive integers, the results for `n-2` and `n-1` will already have been computed and stored in cache by the time it is called on `n`.

Here's an example:

```
Step 0:
  * cache: {}
Step 1 
  * cache: {}
  * call: fast_fib(0) -> 1
Step 2:
  * cache: {fast_fib(0): 1}
  * call: fast_fib(1) -> 1 
Step 3: 
  * cache: {fast_fib(0): 1, fast_fib(1): 1}
  * call: fast_fib(2) -> fast_fib(1) [cached in step 2] + fast_fib(0) [cached in step 1]
Step 4:
  * cache: {fast_fib(0): 1, fast_fib(1): 1, fast_fib(2): 2}
  * call: fast_fib(3) -> fast_fib(2) [cached in step 3] + fast_fib(1) [cached in step 2]
```

Therefore, recursion will always be prevented by retrieval from cache.

If a descending sequence were used, however, the cache could not be used on the first call and `fast_fib(n)` would recurse as expected. Although a subsequent `fast_fib(n-1)` would likely be resolved by cache, depending on whether the cache is large enough to not have had this result overwritten already.